# Nvidia system freeze while loading / unloading DirectX

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze, gaming, nvidia-graphics-card

I build a new PC System with:

- Intel i7-4770
- ASUS Z78 Pro
- Asus Geforce GTX 770
- 8 GB DDR 1333 RAM
- Samsung SSD 840 EVO
- Windows 8.1 64 bit

This system runs smoths, cool and silent. But while loading and unloading games the complete systems freeze very often. I tried Battlefield 4 and Wargame. I can play both games with ultra settings and get high fsp. Most times the systems freeze after the first match, when the PC will load the next map. The monitor get black, the sound freeze and I get no reaction from the PC. My motherboard does not show any error code (only A0).

What I checked already:

- I do not overclock any of the hardware
- I use the newest graphic card and chipset driver (also tried older versions)
- BIOS settings are default
- RAM test is ok
- Cooling is not the problem

After the system fried I must reboot the system via reset button. After the Windows load animations the systems fries very often again. After the second reboot everything is fine.

The freezes happens only while loading / unloading game levels. If I use the PC for work everything works. So I goes the problem must be the graphic card.

Any idea for a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a HDD? If so, try installing the game on that, in case the SSD has a fault. What PSU do you have? Can you try your GTX770 in another computer? Have you tried the GPU in a different PCIx16 slot on the motherboard?

Comment: I have also a HDD. BF4 is installed on the SSD but wargame on the HDD. Both games have the same problem. I have Seasonic X PSU with 650 watt. I did not try the graphic card on another pc. Everything is only 2 weeks old. I think I can install the GPU only at one slot (I must check this tomorrow). I will test my graphic card at another pc. thanks

Comment: The Z87 Pro has two x16 slots and one x4, so there's at least one to try. Good luck!

Comment: Ok I will try. I also checked the windows eventlog. But I see only the shutdown (power reset).

Comment: I can install the graphic card only at the first PCI port, because the cooler is to big for the second slot.

Comment: Is there a possibiliy to check the graphic card for errors? Maybe VRAM check? Can I send my new graphic card to ASUS if I do not know, if the problem is the card?

Comment: You can send it back, but if there are no problems they may charge you (or at least make you pay for the freight). Can you try in another computer first?